# sql query not inserting into table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'sc2broad_testing', '1BananA2');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';


mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (re) VALUES ('Peter')");

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

This code isnt taking the value 'peter' and inserting it into persons row 're'??  should i attempt to tell it which database somewhere?  thanks . it is saying it connects successfully even if i am not telling it which database to connect to?  only the server and user?  i am confused.

Comment: The SQL statement you posted does not 'take the value 'peter' and insert it into persons row 're''. It adds a new row to the table, and sets the 're' column value to 'Peter'. Is this what's confusing you?

Comment: Do `$result = mysql_query(....) or die(mysql_error())` as well. You're assuming the query has succeeded.

Comment: you are not connecting to any database. Use `mysql_select_db('db_name', $link)` before `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may need to specify the database that you are querying to?

```
mysql_select_db('db_name', $link)
```

If not try changing the `mysql_query` to:

```
print("INSERT INTO Persons (re) VALUES ('Peter')");
```

You can then check the query is correct and test it works outside of the php.